# Using framebuffer for postprocessing: can the texture be screen-sized?

Tags: opengl, textures, framebuffer

I have a dilemma. I read that at many places that a texture should not be larger than 1024x1024 pixels, because some GPUs don't support larger sizes.

But if I want to render to a framebuffer, then I have to create a texture, which has the size of the screen, which is nowadays usually larger than 1024x1024, even on mobiles.

Is it guaranteed that I can safely create textures of the size of the native screen resolution of the device?

If there's no "standard" for this, then another formulation of the question: does it happen often that game developers create screen-sized textures? (Because then the manufacturers are forced to support that texture size.)

Comment: Where did you read that? Indeed, all GPU's have a particular size of texture they can handle, but as far as I know that's in the 8K range on modern desktop GPU's. It ultimately comes down to what you want to target with your application, and where you put the line of which hardware you want to support.

Comment: See it this way: can a GPU allocate its own framebuffer if it doesn't suport textures of that size? So allocating the framebuffer with the size of your screen should be no problem as far as I can tell. Either way, you can use `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` to find out what the largest texture size is your GPU supports.

Comment: @Bartvbl: It would be more confirming if someone would say that "i'm in the industry for X centuries, and everyone does this." :) So you are saying that there's no other way technically? Like rendering on multiple textures?

Comment: No. Framebuffers support only a single texture (per attachment). And realistically, are you making an application that's going to be used by millions, or only a few? Is it going to used on one specific device? Or desktops only? Mobile devices only? These decisions are not black and white. As I said before: you have to look at which devices people use, and make a decision based upon that. And since GPU's NEED to be able to ifll the screen with pixels, with the way they are set up nowadays they require the support to use them.

Comment: I want my app to target both desktops (created after 2004) and mobiles (created after 2010). So because a framebuffer can have only one texture per attachment, which implicates that screen-sized textures must be supported? cool

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, this depends on the hardware you intend to use in your project, and the number of devices you wish to support. You need to look at what is available, and where you want to draw the line for the needs of your project. These are very project-specific things usually.

These two show that still slightly more aged graphics cards are well capable of handling 4096x4096 textures:

http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey

http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE

The mobile scene is more difficult, because it is more fragmented. The ARM Mali GPU is a very popular one, though. A model from 2008 also supports 4096x4096 textures:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13314.html

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, gave an upvote, but i'll wait for other answers too. Because my questions were not device specific, because the comparison is with their own native screen resolution of the devices. If your reasoning about the buffer attachments were correct, then I would accept that.

Comment: How can they not be device specific though? Looking at what hardware is used in the market _is_ the way developers make these decisions. The OpenGL specification makes no guarantees about the max texture size supported by an implementation, so the only thing you can do is look at hardware specifications.

Comment: I feel like I'm repeating myself, but because: if no other way exists to render a screen, than to use a texture of the same size, then we have a lower bound for the supported texture size for the GPU of that device, which is the native screen resolution of that device, and no other data is needed for this lower bound.